# Proving this function is continuous and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Fix $a \in X$. For every $x \in X$ we
>   consider the function $$f_x : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: y \mapsto 
>  f_x(y) = d(x,y) - d(a,y). $$ Prove that $f_x$ is continuous and
>   bounded for every $x \in X$.

**Attempt:** Let $x_0 \in X$. I want to prove that $f_x$ is continuous in $x_0$. Let $ \epsilon > 0$. I'm not sure how to pick my $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y \in X$ with $d(x_0, y) < \delta$ I can get $|f_x(x_0) - f_x(y)|$ smaller than epsilon. I have $$ | f_x(x_0) - f_x(y) | = | (d(x,x_0) - d(a,x_0)) - (d(x,y) - d(a,y)) |. $$ I wanted to use the triangle inequality, but this gives me a wrong estimate, since $d(x,a) \leq d(x,x_0) + d(x_0, a)$.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint (?) : $d(x,x_0)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,x_0)$ (and this is also true for $a$ instead of $x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $y,z\in X$
$$\begin{align}
|f_x(y)-f_x(z)|&=|d(x,y)-d(a,y)-d(x,z)+d(a,z)|\\
&\le|d(x,y)-d(x,z)|+|d(a,y)-d(a,z)|\\
&\le2\,d(y,z).
\end{align}
$$
For boundedness observe that
$$
d(x,y)\le d(x,a)+d(a,y)\implies f_x(y)\le d(x,a)
$$
and
$$
d(a,y)\le d(a,x)+d(x,y)\implies f_x(y)\ge -d(x,a).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I use the same argument to prove that $f_x$ is bounded ? I need to find an $ M > 0$ such that $|y - z| \leq M$ for all $y,z \in f(X)$.

Comment: See the edited answer.